# PHP/Sql query for values less than N days

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have a table ("posts") where date is formatted as such (PHP syntax)

```
date = date("F j, Y")
```

and this is the date submitted in the posts table as well. How would I get all posts where date is younger than 7 days (i.e. current_date - 7) via an SQL query?

Any help appreciated

Comment: This is why you shouldn't store your dates as strings

Comment: I would say the same..unfortunately not my code!

Comment: It sucks inheriting a mess like this. Been  there, done that. Didn't like it.

Comment: Also, I assumed MySQL. Is that the actual DB you are using?

Comment: Yes sir..2 minutes until I accept your answer! Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert that date string to an actual date MySQL can work with. You can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) for that.

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date_col, '%M %e, %Y') > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date_col, '%M %e, %Y') > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: This is going to be so murderously slow that for non-trivial amounts of data the column should be converted to a proper `DATE` and indexed. If it can't be converted, you can always add an auxiliary column to store the right values.